# How to set colspan elents width when other columns are dynamic

Tags: css, html

I have a table:-

```html
  <table >
        <thead style="width: calc(100% - 15px); display: table; table-layout: fixed;">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3"></th>
                <th colspan="4">Total</th>
                <th colspan="4">Total</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th>Size</th>
                <th>Min</th>
                <th>Max</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Size</th>
                <th>Min</th>
                <th>Max</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody style="display: block; max-height: 450px; overflow-y: scroll;">
            <tr style="display: table; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; height: 1px;">
                <td>
                    <div>3726</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>20</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>20</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div></div>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display: table; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; height: 1px;">
                <td>
                    <div>3726</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>20</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>20</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div></div>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display: table; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; height: 1px;">
                <td>
                    <div>3726</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>20</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>20</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div></div>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here the two th sections`(<th colspan="4">Total</th><th colspan="4">Total</th>)`are dynamic i.e.,there could be more than two and the th repeats for those 4 columns.

Now, what I want is the first column 'Name' in the sub-header section wider without disturbing the other th. But, due to colspan I can't provide width also colspan="2" not working. I can't make any changes in table-layout also. Is there any way I can get achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `colspan="2"` for "Name" `<th>` solution will work if you add additional column.

To do this change

```
<tr>
  <th colspan="3"></th>
  <th colspan="4">Total</th>
  <th colspan="4">Total</th>
</tr>
```

To

```
<tr>
  <th colspan="4"></th>
  <th colspan="4">Total</th>
  <th colspan="4">Total</th>
</tr>
```